# java exchange operator temp

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand the logic in how to write below statement involving swap/exchange operators. I have googled and searched the text (java intro to problem solving) without any luck thus far. Has anyone struggled on the following before and maybe found an answer (this is an example on strings but I am struggling with swap operators using temp in general):

> There are two String variables, s1 and s2, that have already been declared and initialized. Write some code that exchanges their values.

I know I am supposed to use a temp variable and that is exactly where my logic is null.

The way I wrote it and I know its wrong is the following:

```
temp = s1;
s2 = temp;
```

Comment: The question asks for logic clarification, not a technical solution with even more obscure logic :D

Comment: thanks for the edit as I learn my ways into this forum!

Comment: Try not to see it as a forum. The order of the answers will change with votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all languages:

```
temp = s1; // temporarily store the s1 value because we'll replace it next
s1 = s2; // now s1 lost it's value, and got a new one
s2 = temp; // luckily s2 doesn't go home empty handed, the temp is still good
```

Comment: No :) Just the one's he knows ;)

Comment: I'm sure Python does this in the background, but syntactic sugar makes  us *feel* like we only use the two variables.  Can't think of any other language that wouldn't do it like this, though.

Comment: Assembly: XCHG AX,r16   ; Exchange word register with AX :)

Comment: [s1,s2] = [s2,s1] // ECMAScript.next Sooo... in a sentence: yesterdays design patterns are today's language features.

Comment: @purtip31:  Go borrows a fair bit from Python, so I would've expected that.  I've not messed with the language though.

Answer (score 3):

In your incorrect solution you have lost the value of `s2`. You want to use `temp` to *preserve* the value of either of the variables so that you *don't lose* that value during your swap.

Here's a list of things that you need to do:

- Make a copy of the value of `s1` somewhere.
- Now, with a copy of `s1` stashed away, you can assign to `s1` the value of `s2`.
- Now assign to `s2` the copy that you made of `s1`.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, there is one special case when you don't need a temp variable.

When the two values you want to exchange are of equal length and the language allows you to use bitwise operators on them, you can do a [XOR swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm):

```
A = A bitwise xor B
B = A bitwise xor B
A = A bitwise xor B
```

Though on modern computers this is very rarely practical, it's good to know and demonstrates an interesting aspect of the XOR operation.

Answer (score 0):

Think of variables as containers that can only hold one thing.  To swap the values of two variables, you require three containers.

```
String s1 = "Some string", s2 = "Another string", tmp;
tmp = s1; // put the first item into the third bin
s1 = s2; // put the second item into the first bin
s2 = tmp; // put the first item into the second item
```

Comment: There's no need to initialize `tmp` in the first line.

Comment: No, there isn't; just a habit.

Comment: I always initialize with null. Explicity adds clarity to code meaning :)

Comment: @Adzer: in Java I wouldn't initialize local variables if there is no useful default value. This way you can catch unitialized uses (the compiler will warn you).